# Do I need to include Launch images and App Icons for iphone6 and iphone6 plus while submitting build with Xcode5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I need to submit the build to Apple App store with Xcode 5.1.

1.) Do I need to include Launch Images for Iphone6 and IPhone6 Plus so that users can run on Iphone6 and Iphone6 Plus?
2.) Do I need to include any new App Icons?
3.) Is there anything i need to add which is specific for Iphone6 and Iphone6 plus?

Answer (score 0):

i think that i is not related neither with the devices nor with the Xcode version that you use but with **the iOS versions** that your app will be running on.

Furthermore if  your app will run on iOS 8 ,then you have to add launch images for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus.

As concerning the App icons,here it is a link for the App icons that you have to include.

[App Icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)